# Date difference in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to get a countdown system on my site that countdown only 24hrs from the time of registration.

The idea is after registration, a subscriber has 24hrs to make payment after which he will be blocked. I have the registration time already in my database but i'm stuck with the countdown. I've tried several help online but I don't seem to be getting it right.

The javascript is set to work with the seconds remaining for the user to make payment `var count = '86400';` but i want to use php to calculate from the time registered till the current time how long he has left to register, so that when i refresh the page, it doesn't start from the current time left. So i did this `var count = <?php echo strtotime($row_rsPH['date'])-time(); ?>;`

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
            var count = <?php echo strtotime($row_rsPH['date'])-time(); ?>;
            var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

            function timer() {
                count = count - 1;
                if (count == -1) {
                    clearInterval(counter);
                    return;
                }

                var seconds = count % 60;
                var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
                var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
                minutes %= 60;
                hours %= 60;

                document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds; // watch for spelling
            }




            function startTimer(duration, display) {
                var start = Date.now(),
                    diff,
                    minutes,
                    seconds;
                function timer() {
                    // get the number of seconds that have elapsed since 
                    // startTimer() was called
                    diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

                    // does the same job as parseInt truncates the float
                    minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
                    seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

                    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
                    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

                    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds; 

                    if (diff <= 0) {
                        // add one second so that the count down starts at the full duration
                        // example 05:00 not 04:59
                        start = Date.now() + 1000;
                    }
                };
                // we don't want to wait a full second before the timer starts
                timer();
                setInterval(timer, 1000);
            }

            </script>
            <p>Time Left to make payment: <span id='timer'></span></p>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php

Comment: you've any php for this? it was tagged as such

Comment: Hi @Fred-ii- yes i do `<?php echo strtotime($row_rsPH['date'])-time(); ?>`

Comment: you should update your question with the code/php you tried. Maybe something failed in there.

Comment: question updated @Fred-ii-

Comment: Thanks all for your support. I've sorted it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a countdown sample here http://www.hashemian.com/tools/javascript-countdown.htm and under TargetDate i used this php code

```
<?php
$date = date_create($row_rsPH['date']);
date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 days'));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d h:i A');
?>
```

Hope this helps someone else

Comment: You can select your own answer as correct, if that's how you resolve your question.